# SELECT lastest row based on recent ID filter by certain criteria

Tags: mysql

I have tried a few ways to get the distinct results based on recent id. But still cannot get the correct/valid result because of there are still other criteria to be taken care which I do not know how to get it done.

I tried with a few methods but somehow the group by method will ruin the valid data due to I also need to take care of the uid.

```sql
**With this method I failed to get the correct and valid data from my record.**
select *
from record
WHERE id in (SELECT max(id) FROM record GROUP BY vip_id)
```

```
TABLE:RECORD                
id  company   vip_id    uid   status
1    a        1000      888    pass
2    b        1000      888    pass
3    c        1000      888    pass
4    d        2000      888    pass
5    e        2000      888    fail
6    b        2000      777    pass
```

```
Expected RESULT             
id  company   vip_id    uid   status
3    c        1000      888    pass
5    e        2000      888    fail
```

```
Final Outcome               
uid count(pass)         
888     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM RECORD WHERE id IN (
  SELECT max(id) FROM RECORD WHERE uid = 888 GROUP BY vip_id
);
```

The output is:

```
| id | company | vip_id | uid | status |
|----|---------|--------|-----|--------|
|  3 |       c |   1000 | 888 |   pass |
|  5 |       e |   2000 | 888 |   fail |
```

View the attached [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/126e7e/11).

Comment: Oh now I understand where to add another "WHERE" condition within the select mx(id). It works now. Thank you :)